# How can I align these tables to the top?

Tags: tables, alignment, tabularray

How can I align these tables to the top? The tables currently appear strange, but this is just a minimal example that I am working on. It seems that the Q[c,t] option only works for text and not for tables.

The first example is from the package document so I just copied it there for reference.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}


\begin{tblr}{|Q[l,t]|Q[c,t]|Q[r,t]|}
\hline
{Top Baseline \\ Left Left} & Middle Center & {Right Right \\ Bottom Baseline} \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tblr}{|Q[l,t]|Q[c,t]|Q[r,t]|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
STT        & V       \\ \midrule
1          & 2       \\ \midrule
3          & 4       \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
STT        & V       \\ \midrule
1          & 2       \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular} & {Right Right \\ Bottom Baseline} \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe try `\begin{tabular}[t]`? But why are you mixing tabulars and tabularray tables? My not use a single tblr with multiline and/or merged cells?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz it does not work for me. I'm not good at it, so please feel free to give some suggestion.  I use tabular as it's simpler. It's not easy to merge for a big table with many variants.

Comment: Also I may resize these tables so I think tabular is easier.

Comment: Sam Carter means to add `[t]` to your existing `tabular`, your output image shows the expected alignment for vertically centred tabular, and you want top alignment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, and I apologize for my mistake. That method actually did work. I had added it, but only for one tabular, so I mistakenly believed it was not effective.